# What is the amplitude of image performing SHM?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I wanted to know if there is a general formula to figure out the amplitude of an image formed if the object performing SHM about the principal axis or perpendicular to it at some position of a simple, Concave, Convex and all lenses (biconcave & convex,plano concave & convex, concavo-convex and convexo-concave).

One numerical I have solved only involved axial SHM (about the principal axis) and involves a simple multiplication of the image's magnification and the objects oscillate along the principal axis with some amplitude. Why would we use its magnification, why wouldn't the image just have the same amplitude?